# Histogram of dataframe on column groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following `df`:

```
df
   user      start                end           mode
0   82  2009-04-19 05:49:50 2009-04-19 06:17:40 metro
1   82  2009-04-19 06:18:05 2009-04-19 06:22:44 foot
2   10  2007-06-26 11:32:29 2007-06-26 11:40:29 bus
3   10  2008-03-28 14:52:54 2008-03-28 15:59:59 metro
4   20  2011-08-27 06:13:01 2011-08-27 08:01:37 foot
5   20  2012-02-20 14:10:33 2012-02-20 14:29:59 bus
6   20  2012-02-21 01:22:05 2012-02-21 01:55:47 bus
```

So I want group my df by `mode` column and plot histogram for `(year, month)` showing how many of each mode are there in that month of that year.

So I do:

```
df[['mode']].groupby([df['start'].dt.year, df['start'].dt.month]).count().plot(kind='barh')
```

output:
[image]

The result is cumulative value of `mode` for each month.

But I want to see the number of each `mode` (where available) in every month of each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use seaborn and pass the `hue` paramter.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [82, 82, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20],
 'start': ['2009-04-19 05:49:50',
  '2009-04-19 06:18:05',
  '2007-06-26 11:32:29',
  '2008-03-28 14:52:54',
  '2011-08-27 06:13:01',
  '2012-02-20 14:10:33',
  '2012-02-21 01:22:05'],
 'end': ['2009-04-19 06:17:40',
  '2009-04-19 06:22:44',
  '2007-06-26 11:40:29',
  '2008-03-28 15:59:59',
  '2011-08-27 08:01:37',
  '2012-02-20 14:29:59',
  '2012-02-21 01:55:47'],
 'mode': ['metro', 'foot', 'bus', 'metro', 'foot', 'bus', 'bus']})


df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])


df['year'] = df.start.dt.year
df['month'] = df.start.dt.month
df = df.groupby(['year','month','mode']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
g = sns.barplot(data=df, y=df['year'].astype(str)+','+df['month'].astype(str),x='count', hue='mode', orient='h')
plt.ylim(reversed(plt.ylim()));
```

[image]